# Reloading embed PDF in a DIV (empty Accrobat Reader error popup)

Tags: embed, acrobat

I have a web application coded in C#/ASP.NET.  The application basically exports a PDF file when the user click on Save.  It then reloads a DIV, putting the EMBED (with the src pointing to the newly generated pdf file) in it.  Sometimes the embed area just gets black and I get this window from Acrobat Reader: http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3359/acreader.jpg.  What does it mean?  Has anyone ever see this?

Answer (score 0):

embedding PDF's in web pages is pretty rubbish overall. Try using the open source lib FlexPaper instead;

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com